# Remove BR tag from Linecontrol HtmlEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the [LineControl Html Editor](http://suyati.com/linecontrol-jquery-text-editor-plugin/) in my site, and I have noticed that when I add new lines, this is represented by a `br` tag.

This `BR` may work fine, but it causes an error when I parse the result using an XHTML parser.

How do I update LineControl script to remove this `<BR>` or change it for a `<BR/>` tag?

Thank you.

Comment: As with any plugin if that option isn't documented ... read the source. If solution not found doing that find another editor that is more configurable

Comment: Thank you charlietfl. Yes, I reviewed the javascript source, but I couldn't find any solution. I took a different approach to this problem and remove the XHTML parser that was optional in may code.